# Applying transformation matrix to new set of points

Tags: python, opencv, coordinates

I have predicted the transformation matrix between two sets of points as follows,

pt_a = [(590, 291), (676, 286), (683, 363), (597, 370)]

pt_b = [(612, 276), (699, 273), (702, 349), (616, 353)]

```
transform_matrix, _ = cv2.estimateAffinePartial2D (np.array([pt_a]), np.array(pt_b))

if transform_matrix is not None:
        dx = transform_matrix[0, 2]
        dy = transform_matrix[1, 2]
        da = np.arctan2(transform_matrix[1, 0], transform_matrix[0, 0])

        print(dx,dy,da)
```

Now how do we apply this transformation matrix to a new set of points for predicting its new positions? The following are the points upon which I would like to apply this transformation matrix.

```
pt_c =[(303, 569), (321, 559), (325, 571)]
```

Comment: It's really just a matrix multiply. But if you want a `cv2` function, then look at [warpAffine](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html)

Comment: May I know what I must multply with transformation_matrix?

Comment: I'm more interested about finding the new coordinates based on the reference?

Comment: I wasn't correct earlier. Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpaffine#warpaffine). This is what is implemented: `dst(x, y) = src(M_11*x + M_12y + M_13, M_21*x + M_22y + M_23)`

Comment: I tried new_x, new_Y = M_11 * x + M_12 * y + M_13, M_21 * x + M_22 * y + M_23 but it is not working unfortunately :(

Comment: Did you try to use the warpAffine method?

Comment: warpaffine works but I would like to find the coordinates with respect to the original image than in the warped image

Comment: If you are going from dst image to src image, then you need to take the inverse of the transformation matrix

Comment: `transform_matrix, _ =  np.array(cv2.estimateAffinePartial2D(np.array([pt_a]), np.array(pt_b)))
transform_matrix_inv = np.linalg.inv(transform_matrix)` Im using this code to find the inverse but for some reason its throwing linalg error. Am I doing it properly?

Comment: @gnodab do you mean the transpose?

Comment: This is a little tricky. I bet it's throwing an error because your transformation matrix is not square. This is because it is an affine transform. So the bottom row (which is not typically included) is `[0 0 1]`. OpenCV fortunately has a function to our rescue: [invertAffineTransform](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpaffine#void%20invertAffineTransform(InputArray%20M,%20OutputArray%20iM))